# CRM 2013 Mailbox Delete Email After Processing

Tags: exchange-server, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

[image]
My CRM in sync with a Exchange Server. When i activate this option in mailbox configrations, it deletes mails permanently from Email Exchange server. But i want to move them to "Deleted Items" folder instead of deleting them permanently. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this configuration going to be for all your users or for a 'system mailbox'? If it is a system mailbox i would think about configuring this server side as i don't believe this is a way to change the configuration from within CRM. hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

CRM issues a HardDelete request to the Exchange EWS API, unfortunately there is no obvious way of configuring this.